# Why does viewport produce a strange result

Tags: graphics

I use `pdflatex` to compile the following input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=10 10 20 20]{bald.png}}
\end{document}
```

The image to be imported is:

[image]

But the resulting PDF looks very strange as follows:

[image]

Note: the gray frame is Adobe Reader background, it is not the part of PDF output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'd forgotten to clip

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=10 10 20 20,clip]{bald.png}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks quite normal. You are setting a small viewport, so for latex the graphic is only 10x10pt large. The rest of the graphics "sticks" out. Use clip if you want to see the part set by viewport.